# «Son tort était»?

Tags: expressions

J'écoutais un podcast, dont je ne me souviens plus le nom, où l'interlocuteur semblait dire «son tort» au lieu de «son erreur». Est-ce que l'usage de cette expression est correcte?

Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: Les deux mots ne sont pas synonymes, peux-tu donner la phrase ou le contexte dans lequel ils sont employés ? Si tu ne peux pas reproduire la phrase exacte l'adresse du podcast, et l'index pourrait suffire.

Comment: Je ne suis pas choqué par cette expression. Ça me paraît équivalent.

Comment: @Laure Je suis désolé, mais je n'ai pas pu le trouver. Et d'ailleurs, qu'est-ce que l'index?

Comment: À quel endroit de l'enregistrement se trouve la phrase. On ne peut pas dire quel mot convient (tort ou erreur) si on ne connaît pas la pharse.

Comment: @Laure malheureusement, il m'est impossible de la trouver... Je pensais que ce serait plus facile. Merci, en tout cas. (ou quand même?) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'erreur c'est le simple fait de se tromper. Quand on parle de tort on exprime non seulement le fait qu'on s'est trompé mais on porte en plus un jugement moral.

> Mon tort est de ne pas avoir dit la vérité.

→ En disant cela je porte un jugement moral, je me reproche moralement de ne pas avoir dit la vérité.

> Mon erreur est de ne pas avoir dit la vérité.

→ Je fais le simple constat de m'être trompé.

On peut aussi employer le mot « tort » dans le cas d'infraction à un ordre établi (juridique ou autre). Dans ce cas on ne pourrait pas employer le mot erreur (trop faible).  Si je cause un accident de la route parce que je n'ai pas respecté le code de la route je dis :

> Je suis dans mon tort.